# Error UIViewController has no member

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Currently working on my app, to learn swift (Im completely new). And I came across an error that I just cant seem to resolve. 
I have two views in my storyboard with two viewcontrollers hence ViewController & Settings.

On the "Settings" view I have a `textfield`, and on the "ViewController" view i have a label.

I want to pass text from the textfield on "settings" to my label on "viewcontroller"

Currently i get the following error:

> value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'ViewController'

My code looks somewhat like this for the input field:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var secondVC: ViewController = segue.destination.ViewController as ViewController

    secondVC.receivedString = textField.text!
}
```

for the label:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var city: UILabel!
var receivedString: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    label.text = receivedString
}
```

the "label.text" gives me an unresolved identifier too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the destination `viewController` in Swift 3 it is just `segue.destination` not `segue.destination.ViewController`.

```
var secondVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
```

For second error you have declare `UILabel` with name `city` not `label` so it must be `city.text = receivedString`

Comment: hmm, it did remove the error, if i decide to say: 

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! ViewController
        
        secondVC.label = textField.text!

Comment: I guess thats what i have done? Is it not best practice to do so?

Comment: @JeppeC In your question you are passing the string with object `receivedString`and assign text of city label in `viewDidLoad` that is the correct way to pass data because in `prepare(for:sender:)` UILabel object is not initialize yet.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Oh and by the way! Just for the logic of it, now that i have made the segue, - will i then be able to just pass more objects without writing the entire function again? :-)

Comment: Please explain your question in detail what do you mean by "will i then be able to just pass more objects without writing the entire function again?"

Comment: sorry, but i mean if i have another input that i want to pass to a new label on the same view, will i then just be able to place a new one under like this, instead of writing the entire function again: 

Mainview.label = textField.text!
Mainview.label2 = textField2.text!

Comment: Yes under the same function initialize as many as you want to pass to second viewController.